# Update Yoast meta title of Woocommerce product category via the WP REST API

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api

I have a Wordpress + Woocommerce website and I want to update the Yoast meta title and meta description of a product category via the REST API.

So I have installed this plugin :

https://github.com/ChazUK/wp-api-yoast-meta

```
And added this code :

// Product cat
register_rest_field( 'product_cat',
'yoast_meta',
array(
'get_callback' => array( $this, 'wp_api_encode_yoast_tag' ),
'update_callback' => null,
'schema' => null,
)
);
```

In the add_yoast_data function but it did not work, I can't fill those fields from the rest API (but it works with posts, pages..)

(to fill those field via the API, I use this code (it works for products, but not for product categories) :

```
$data = [
        'name' => "title",
        'description' => "text",
        'yoast_meta' => [
            'yoast_wpseo_title' => "yoast title",
            'yoast_wpseo_metadesc' => "yoast desc",
        ]
    ];

    $options = [
        CURLOPT_URL => 'domain.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/categories',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode("$consumer_key:$consumer_secret"),
            'Content-Type: application/json',
        ],
    ];

    // Initialisation de cURL
    $ch = curl_init();
```

Of course, I have contacted the plugin authors, no reply so far.

Has anyone already tried to do that? Without using any plugin...

The register_rest_field should work.

Thanks